# display @misc reference in order of key appearance

Tags: latex, bibtex

I can't seem to find the option for ordering a reference item based on appearance of the key values in cite. I have the following in my .bib file:

```
@misc{test,
  author = "Test",
  title = "Title",
  note = "6 October 2016",
  howpublished = "\url{https://www.google.nl}"
}
```

which gives the following:

[image: Current]

However I would like to have the reference item in the order: **[Author, Title, Note, Howpublished]** just as I have described in the @misc. Is this possible?

Comment: One can specify the ordering for a particular `@type` bibliography type under [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). Are you able to consider this? This would be consistent for all types referenced in such a way. That is, you can define all `@misc` types to show **[Author, Title, Note, Howpublished]**.

Comment: That is indeed prefered, as all my @misc types would need to be displayed in such way.